# Beamer: How to add "Year" information to footcite?

Tags: beamer, biblatex

I have the following citation in Bib.bib

```
@article{abramov_gordon_feldman_chavarga,
title={Sex \& vision I: Spatio-temporal resolution},
volume={3},
DOI={10.1186/2042-6410-3-20},
number={1},
journal={Biology of Sex Differences},
author={Abramov, Israel and Gordon, James and Feldman, Olga and Chavarga, Alla},
year={2012},
pages={20}
}
```

And my slide is as follows:

[image]

However, the footcite is not displaying the year of the paper, which is **2012**

I have consulted several other posts, but they are not about footcite but about creating custom citation, and the methods are usually complicated.

**Is there a simple modification to the code below that allows me to generate the year information in the footnote using footcite?**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[style=authortitle,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{transparent}
%Information to be included in the title page:
\title{Sample title}
\author{Anonymous}
\institute{ShareLaTeX}
\date{2017}

\begin{document}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Unbeatable Slide}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> My First Citation \footcite{abramov_gordon_feldman_chavarga}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\footnote{\Citeauthor{}, \citetitle{}, \citeyar{}}`? Or you need to use a style which includes the citation format you want. You're using `authortitle`. Obviously, that cites by author and title. Remember, it is only a citation - a direction to an entry in a bibliography with the relevant details. Do people need author, title and year to distinguish this entry uniquely?

Comment: @cfr \footnote{\Citeauthor{abramov_gordon_feldman_chavarga}, \citetitle{abramov_gordon_feldman_chavarga}, \citeyear{abramov_gordon_feldman_chavarga}} doesn't seem to work :( and it says style = authortitleyear not found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can patch the `cite` macro to add the date:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{cite}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:title}}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:title}%
   \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
   \usebibmacro{date}}
   {}
   {}
```

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[style=authortitle,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{abramov_gordon_feldman_chavarga,
  title={Sex \& vision I: Spatio-temporal resolution},
  volume={3},
  DOI={10.1186/2042-6410-3-20},
  number={1},
  journal={Biology of Sex Differences},
  author={Abramov, Israel and Gordon, James and Feldman, Olga and Chavarga, Alla},
  year={2012},
  pages={20}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{cite}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:title}}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:title}%
   \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
   \usebibmacro{date}}
   {}
   {}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Unbeatable Slide}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> My First Citation \footcite{abramov_gordon_feldman_chavarga}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]