# How to insert a reference with Author, Date, Title with BibLateX in a Tufte-Book document?

Tags: biblatex, tufte

I use BibLateX in a Tufte-book document class, and I want to apply a style with Author, Date, Title to the references in footnotes. I found a style which approaches this but the year is missing, as follow:

```
\documentclass[nobib,symmetric,justified,marginals=raggedouter]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[style=authortitle-icomp,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
```

How can I create a specific style in order to have Author, Date and Title ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very similar question can be found at [Partial and complete citations with biblatex in the same document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/508121/35864).

Here I'd choose option 3 to define a new command that we can map to `\autocite`. With your settings and the desired output it seems appropriate to base the style on `authoryear-ibid` (I didn't take `style=authortitle-icomp` because you sort `nyt`, which suggests the year is more important than the title and you also want the date before the title in citations).

```
\documentclass[british,nobib,symmetric,justified,marginals=raggedouter]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-icomp]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{adtcite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
       {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
          {\setunit{\compcitedelim}}
          {\printnames{labelname}%
           \setunit*{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
           \printlabeldateextra
           \setunit*{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
           \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:title}}}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}%
  \setunit{\multicitedelim}}
\makeatother

\newbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\fadtcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{adtcite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\fadtcites}[\mkbibfootnote]{\fadtcite}{\setunit{\multicitedelim}}

\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{fadt}{\fadtcite}{\fadtcites}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{autocite=fadt}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem\autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum\autocite{sigfridsson}
dolor\autocite{cicero}
sit\autocite{worman}
amer\autocite{geer,nussbaum}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998, ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’.]

Comment: Your solution works, Thanks, but these modifications change the title layout of parts of my document. I will describe the problem in another question to solve it.