# Citations in a two-column environment as a description list

Tags: biblatex, multicol, description

Using the example given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/508241/306838) (section 3), I'd like the `\autocite` command to produce a two-column list of partial citations.

The MWE below does not compile. I get the following error:

```
 LaTeX Error: \begin{description} on input line 81 ended by \end{multicols}.
```

By removing either the `description` environment or the `multicol` environment, it compiles. How can I have it compile using both environments?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@Book{Goossens2003,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
  date      = {2003},
  title     = {The LATEX companion},
  edition   = {[Nachdr.]},
  isbn      = {0201775913},
  location  = {Boston},
  pagetotal = {528},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  series    = {Addison-Wesley series on tools and techniques for computer typesetting},
}
@Article{Knuth1984,
  author       = {D. E. Knuth},
  date         = {1984-02},
  journaltitle = {The Computer Journal},
  title        = {Literate Programming},
  doi          = {10.1093/comjnl/27.2.97},
  number       = {2},
  pages        = {97--111},
  volume       = {27},
  publisher    = {Oxford University Press ({OUP})},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{jobname.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=doi, null]
    }
  }
}

\newbibmacro*{fajycite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\printnames{labelname}%
       \setunit*{\space}%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
       \printdate}%
       \setunit*{\addcolon\space}%
       \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
       \addperiod%
       }
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}%
    }

\DeclareCiteCommand{\fajycite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}%
\begin{multicols}{2}%
\begin{description}\item%
}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{fajycite}}
  {\item
  }
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}%
  \end{description}%
  \end{multicols}%
}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\fajycites}{\fajycite}{}

\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{fajy}{\fajycite}{\fajycites}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{autocite=fajy}

\let\myautocite\autocite
\renewcommand{\autocite}{\noindent\myautocite}


\begin{document}
\autocite{Goossens2003, Knuth1984}
\end{document}
```